# Cordova, Phonegap Crash Reports

Tags: cordova

I'm currently experiencing random crashes with Cordova and currently having problems replicating it, do you know if it's possible to log crash reports to an external serveR?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try Splunk MINT ( Bugsense) => https://mint.splunk.com/

All uncontrolled crashes can be viewed in MINT console.

Example (put the Mint libraries in path). There is also available in IOS and is possible to trace HTML5 events.

```
package edu.esade.yourapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class YourApp extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mint.initAndStartSession(this, MINT_API_KEY);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

}
```